# Tooltip for Cell-based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a view which (among other elements) holds a cell based NSTableView. I made the ViewController the delegate of the table. The view controller is created programmatically and added to an NSStatusItem.

I implemented:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldShowCellExpansionForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView toolTipForCell:(NSCell *)aCell rect:(NSRectPointer)rect tableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)row mouseLocation:(NSPoint)mouseLocation {
    return @"A tooltip";
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldTrackCell:(NSCell *)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    NSLog(@"Display");
}
```

But when I run my code the only one of these methods that gets called is:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

My real objective is to dinamycally define the tooltips for my cells.

Comment: Is it possible that the NSMenuItem in which the view is embedded is swallowing the tooltip event?

Answer (score 0):

I've just needed to solve this problem for my app's development.
These delegate methods you mentioned above are only for the expansion tooltip of a text cell, that shows full text when truncated.
A possible solution is to add an observer of NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification in which the tooltip rectangles are rearranged using addToolTipRect:owner:userData:. The code is something like:

```
NSTableView *tableView; // the target tableview

- (void)tableViewSizeDidChange:(NSNotification *)theNotification {
    [tableView removeAllToolTips];
    for (NSInteger row = 0; row < tableView.numberOfRows; row ++) {
        NSRect rowRect = [tableView rectOfRow:row];
        for (NSInteger col = 0; col < tableView.numberOfColumns; col ++) {
            NSRect colRect = [tableView rectOfColumn:col];
            NSRect cellRect = NSIntersectionRect(rowRect, colRect);
            [tableView addToolTipRect:cellRect owner:
                /* Tooltip string for cell at row and col */ userData:NULL];
    }}
}

- (void)windowDidLoad {
...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(tableViewSizeDidChange:)
        name:NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification object:tableView];
...
```

You may also need to call tableViewSizeDidChange: when a table column was moved or resized.